# Is it possible to take screenshots inside Chutzpah?

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, chutzpah

Is it possible to take screenshots inside Chutzpah?

<strike>I can't seem to get to the underlying phantom object.</strike> 
I understand now looking through the chutzpahRunner.js that the test itself is called via page.open() so appears to be in a different scope.

In the end I'm hoping to diff svg elements similar to how PhantomCSS does it with casperjs.

I'm new to phantomjs / chutzpah so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the co-ordinator of Chutzpah:

> This is not something Chutzpah supports. Chutzpah is focused on
>   running js tests. I think CasperJS is a better fit to what you are
>   looking for.

Though it would be a cool feature, it's being discussed in the Chutzpah forum: [Screenshots via phantomjs](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/discussions/538643)